# How can i abstract this if, else statement?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

```
if (active)
   classes.container = classes.container.replace(
     classModifiers.active.container.remove,
     classModifiers.active.container.add
   );
 else
   classes.container = classes.container.replace(
     classModifiers.active.container.add,
     classModifiers.active.container.remove
   );

 if (active)
   classes.icon = classes.icon.replace(
     classModifiers.active.icon.remove,
     classModifiers.active.icon.add
   );
 else
   classes.icon = classes.icon.replace(
     classModifiers.active.icon.add,
     classModifiers.active.icon.remove
   );

 if (active)
   classes.badge = classes.badge.replace(
     classModifiers.active.badge.remove,
     classModifiers.active.badge.add
   );

 else
   classes.badge = classes.badge.replace(
     classModifiers.active.badge.add,
     classModifiers.active.badge.remove
   );
```

I don`t know how to abstract it. I have repeat it 3 times because i couldn't find another solution. Help me guys to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
classes.container = doMagic(classes.container, "container");
classes.icon = doMagic(classes.icon, "icon");
classes.badge = doMagic(classes.badge, "badge");

const doMagic = (element, fieldName) =>
    element.replace(
        classModifiers.active[fieldName][active ? "remove" : "add"],
        classModifiers.active.container[active ? "add" : "remove"]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const replacer = (entity, active) => {
  classes[entity].replace(classModifiers.active[entity][active ? 'remove' : 'add'], classModifiers.active[entity][active ? 'add' : 'remove']);
};
classes.container = replacer('container', active);
classes.icon = replacer('icon', active);
classes.badge = replacer('badge', active);
```

May be, like this?

Comment: Proablem is in the replace return. I work in typscript and he give me eror, i canot return replace

Comment: I have edited my solution

Answer (score 0):

You can access an object property using the [] notation
Like this:

```
['container', 'icon', 'badge'].forEach(pname => {
    if (active)
        classes.container = classes.container.replace(
            classModifiers.active[pname].remove,
            classModifiers.active[pname].add);
    else 
        classes.container = classes.container.replace(
            classModifiers.active[pname].add,
            classModifiers.active[pname].remove);
})
```